# Front end flashdata / system messaging without URL segments

Tags: system-messages

I'd like to be able to display incidental messages on the front end, such as for 'thank-you' content and success/error messages after form submissions. However, I'd like to do this without polluting the URLs with extra segments... Is there a standard solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, cookies would be the way to go here if you don't want extra segments. [Cookies Plus](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cookie-plus) looks like it could make this easy for you (though there are some negative reviews ... no harm in giving it a shot of course, it would save you from writing this custom or adding PHP into your templates).

First, your form would redirect to **forms/submit/success**.

In that template you'd put:

```
{exp:cookie_plus:set name="flash_message" value="Your entry was submitted." seconds="10"}
{redirect="forms/submit"}
```

Then in your **forms/submit** template:

```
{exp:cookie_plus:get name="flash_message"}
{if cookie}
    <p class="message success">{cookie}</p>
{/if}
{/exp:cookie_plus:get}
```

You can get more elaborate if you want to conditionally check for different cookie names that represent different kinds of messages, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this Derek. Your answer prompted me to realise that Stash can solve this problem in basically the same way using {exp:stash:set name="flash_message" scope="user" save="yes"}Message{/exp:stash:set} and setting the stash_cookie_expire config variable.